# My site is blocked by certain work place's web filter

Tags: html

My site http://www.wearemop.com is being blocked by some work place filters, apparently it is being flagged as a sex/porn site. There is nothing on the site that should raise this flag i.e. it does not contain the word "sex" anywhere on it.

I don't know exactly what web filters are giving this result though I am enquiring to find out more information.

I haven't had much luck searching this issue so if anybody could provide some tips to make the site appear more legitimate in the eyes of web filters then that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [WebPulse Site Review Request](http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp)
The page you want reviewed is http://www.wearemop.com/   (check another site)
This page is currently categorized as Business/Economy
This page was rated by our WebPulse system

Comment: I think this topic must be here instead: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voting to close as off topic, as this is not a programming problem. However, most workplace web filters use a third-party block-list. You'll need to find which filter provider(s) have blocked you and why. Getting de-listed from blocks like this can be difficult and time consuming. Good luck. (it's worth noting that many blocks are put in place because a site has been hacked and does have some bad content on it, even if the site owner is not aware of it. You may want to double check for this before doing anything else)